# How to asynchronously reset values redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reactjs-flux, redux-framework

--For starters apologies for the ambiguous title. The issue I am having I'm really confused how to put the title. I am open to edits. 
Basically, I am using react-redux and I have a modal in which I am updating some contents in the database. On update, I want all the reducer state to default and close the modal. (**That is straight forward as I am triggering a function on update that sets all values to default**) 
However, on update I want to close the modal and display a toastr on update or error message from the response. **I have set up components and actions for the toastr.**

The problem is that the toastr doesn't display the message because before it can match the constant action from the store, the reducers for the modal are already set to default. What would be the best approach to overcome this?

**Modal.jsx**

```
//update 
   updateConfig() {
            this.props.updateConfigNode(node, latestConfigData); //update action
            this.closeModal(); 
        }
    closeModal() {
        this.props.status(false); //Close modal
        this.props.update(''); //Set update action status 'updated or error' to ''
      }
```

**Toastr.jsx**

```
    componentDidUpdate() {
     this.routerConfigNotification(this.props.config); //Getting from store
   }
    configNotify(config) {
        const message = checkForRouterConfigUpdateState(config);
    if(message) {
            this._addNotificationNormal(message.title, message.type, message.text);
          }
    }
```

**Utils**

```
    export function checkForRouterConfigUpdateState(routerConfig) {

  let message = {};
  let messageText;

  switch (_.get(routerConfig, 'updateStatus')) {
case '_error':
      messageText = 'An error has been occurred while updating configuration';
      return message = {
        mode: 'normal',
        title: 'Error',
        type: 'info',
        status: _.get(routerConfig, 'updateStatus'),
        text: messageText
      };

    case '_updated':
      messageText = 'Successfully Updated';
      return message = {
        mode: 'normal',
        title: 'Updated',
        type: 'info',
        status: _.get(routerConfig, 'updateStatus'),
        text: messageText
      };
}
}
```

I have tried other lifecycle update methods but the closest I have been to solving this issue is to use setTimeout function which I know is a hack and I am pretty sure there is a way to tackle these sort of async problems. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Umm, shot in a dark, but why do you insist on reseting modal state on update? Just reset it on before it's opened and you're golden, no?

Comment: Tried that but see if there is another action trigger in between the toastr for update would modal would show because I haven't set the state to default. Get my point?

Comment: Thunk is used for async actions in redux. Have you looked into it?

Comment: Yeah and I'm using it as well but that doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Is `this.props.updateConfigNode(node, latestConfigData)` a promise? If so you can put `closeModal` into a `then` block so that it's only called when your request is done.

```
this.props.updateConfigNode(node, latestConfigData).then(() => {
  this.closeModal();
});
```

Comment: It's not a promise.